# Python using function with if

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to do the following thing :

```
myChain = myChain(a,b) if a & b else "do_nothing"
```

Is there a way to do it this way ?

Or should I stick with the usual :

```
if a & b: 
   myChain = myChain(a,b)
```

Thanks !

Comment: _"Is there a way to do it this way?"_ Yes, and the way to do it is the way you did it. In other words, your first code block is perfectly valid syntax. (it's a little unusual that you're using `&` instead of `and`, and overshadowing the `myChain` function with a local variable, but both are legal)

Comment: You are missing the `else` case in version 2, so any subsequent reference to `myChain` will refer to the function, *not* its result (on a related note, **don't** give them the same name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a way to do your second code block in a single line, you may delete the newline:

```
if a & b: myChain = myChain(a,b)
```

If you absolutely don't want to use an `if` statement, you could use a conditional expression like you did in your first code block. But this is an unusual way to do it.

```
myChain = myChain(a,b) if a & b else myChain
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on what you're going for; are you meaning to assign "do_nothing" to `myChain`? That's what both of these will do. If that's fine, then you're fine -- otherwise, would probably prefer

```
if a and b:
    myNewChain = myChain(a, b) #why assign to the same name as the function/class?
else:
    myNewChain = None
```

...or whatever `None` should actually be.

If you're using this for flow control -- which it seems like you might be, given the name of the string -- it's typically discouraged to do so, just because people expect to see assignment when there's a ternary operator. Whether or not there's an actual problem with doing it that way, I am admittedly uncertain.